# Using VirtualBox USB capabilities 

Tags: usb, virtualbox

Using the USB capabilities of the VirtualBox, I've tried in tried different computers and just keep receiving the message that the USB device is busy with a previous request.
I'm trying to access the USB stuff since the first version (now using 3.0.4), but I was never successful.

Is there any special configuration or tweak to make?

Comment: Did you install Guest Additions and are you using the VirtualBox standard or OSE?  As far as I know the open source edition doesn't support USB.

Comment: I've installed the Guest Additions and I'm using the OSE version. I've tried with XP and Vista. Everything looks fine, the USB driver is installed on the host on the first time an USB resquest is made but nothing happens on the guest, and when I try to access the device again I receive the "device is busy" message.

Comment: I have XP and Vista Guests over a Vista Host and Windows 7 Guest over a XP Host.

Comment: I ran into the same problem (VBox OSE), and found that rebooting helped.  After that, I really didn't have any problems.

Comment: Well, in fact rebooting both guest and host helped indeed. It doesn't work flawlessly though. But I really should have tried the default windows action for panic situations, aka reboot. I guess I deserve a forcible relocation to an agrarian society. http://www.dilbert.com/strips/comic/2008-12-24/

Comment: VirtualBox only works correctly the *first* time you do something.  The second and subsequent times you try to do it, it breaks.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same problem after upgrading from VirtualBox 2.2.2 to 3.1.6, and regrettably rebooting had no effect. However, after searching for a long time, I found the solution on the [VirtualBox forum](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=106786#p106786):

With VirtualBox shut down, remove the USB device from your host. Then restart VirtualBox, start the virtual machine, and then reattach the USB device. Now, VirtualBox recognizes the devices.

**Note**: I did the test with Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to set a USB filter and also enable USB for the virtual machine. Under the settings of your virtual machine, go to the USB tab. You will want to make sure the USB Controller is enabled first and foremost. Then (while your usb device is plugged in) add a filter for it, the process is fairly straightforward.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Source: I have the OP's problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you just put in whatever USB device you want to pass through (I normally use USB keys) in the settings, fire up the VM, and it works.

Did you install the host USB controller when you installed VirtualBox?  What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

With Mac OS X Lion and VirtualBox 4.1.4 I *had to reboot* the MAC (guest). Then adding the filter and plugging the device when the VM is running correctly captures the USB device.